# Select Random records from table but for each region; 3 records from each of 4 regions, and 18 records from the remaining 2 regions

Tags: sql, oracle, select, oracle11g

I need some help figuring out how to select a total of 30 random records from a table of over 10000+ records in an Oracle table. I have looked elsewhere but the other solutions all seem to be selecting an equal number of random records from each category. I am using Oracle SQL Developer if that helps.

My query needs to select 3 random records from each of the 4 regions, but also select a total of 18 records from the other 2 regions. The total number of random records should be 30 and shouldn't contain repeated records with every run of the query.

We have 6 sales regions (Red,Blue,Green,Black,Orange,Purple) and we want to randomly reward 3 salesmen from each of the Red, Blue, Green, and Black regions; but also randomly reward a total of 18 salesmen from the other two regions of Orange and Purple.

This is what I have so far. I am not so advanced with SQL so I ask you to please be kind.

I have failed to figure out how to select the 18 from the combination of Orange and Purple regions.

```
select * from
       ( select salesman_id,sales_region,supervisor, row_number()
                over (partition by sales_region order by dbms_random.value) as num_row
         from   sales_table
         group by salesman_id,sales_region,supervisor )
where num_row <=3;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You basically have the right idea. You just need to treat the Orange and Purple regions as one, and have a different condition for the different regions:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   (SELECT salesman_id, 
                CASE
                     WHEN sales_region IN ('Oranage', 'Purple') THEN 'Special'
                     ELSE sales_region
               END AS sales_region, 
               supervisor, 
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CASE
                                               WHEN sales_region IN ('Oranage', 'Purple')
                                                    THEN 'Special'
                                               ELSE sales_region
                                               END
                           ORDER BY dbms_random.value) AS num_row
         FROM  sales_table) t
WHERE (sales_region = 'Special' AND num_row <= 18) OR (num_row <= 3)
```

Comment: Neat, but you'll need to repeat that `case` expression to define the custom `sales_region` column within the inline view. Also check spelling of `'Special'` and `num_row` ;)

Comment: @WilliamRobertson true, true and true. Edited and fixed - thanks for noticing!

Comment: @Mureinik This is exactly what I wanted to achieve. Thank you.